# Browser generating unwanted markup when retrieving innerHTML of child elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm in the process of creating a content editor and as part of this I need to retrieve the inner HTML of any elements that are contained within a react container (i.e. held within a span with a data-reactid).

I'm storing strings retrieved from the DOM and comparing them to a batch of new strings for replacement, however when trying to obtain the innerHTML of the nested content I've found that additional unwanted markup is being generated.

As an example, I have the following string which I'm placing into the retrieveInner function as argument 'oldValue':

```js
var old_value = "<span data-reactid=\".1qw3srjo8hs.1.3.$2.$2.0.$0.$0.$0.$0.$1.$1.$2.0\"><div class=\"case-study-box float-left margin-top-20\">VIEW OUR NUMBERS<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right margin-left-5\"></span></div></span>"

var new_value = retrieveInner(old_value);

console.log("returned value", new_value);

function retrieveInner(oldValue) {
  let container = document.createElement('div');
  container.innerHTML = oldValue;

  if (container.children[0]) {
    oldValue = container.children[0].innerHTML; // <- unwanted markup generated here
    console.log('old value', oldValue);
  }
  return oldValue;
}
```

Now, if I code the retrieveInner function into my browser and place the oldValue string into it, I'm given the following return value which is precisely what I want:

```
"<div class="case-study-box float-left margin-top-20">VIEW OUR NUMBERS<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right margin-left-5"></span></div>"
```

In practice though, I'm getting the following returned value as demonstrated by the console log:

```
"<div class="\&quot;case-study-box" float-left="" margin-top-20\"="">VIEW OUR NUMBERS<span class="\&quot;glyphicon" glyphicon-chevron-right="" margin-left-5\"=""></span></div>"
```

Completely boggled by why this is occurring and why there's a disconnect between my console log and what I've been trying in my dev console(on Chrome). Can anyone shed any insight and advise how I can get the desired string returned?

Thanks

Comment: I converted your code sample into a live demo. I can't reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

seems as if your first className (e.g. case-study-box) is surrounded by quotes and the browser tries to fix that.